# How to create login in Sencha Touch

Tags: model, controller, sencha-touch-2, store

I'm newbie in sencha and I've create a Login.js. But I have a problem don't know how to keep the data and which database that Sencha Touch compatible with. Please someone assist me how to store,model and controller.

Login.js

```
Ext.define('RealApp.view.Login', {
extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
alias: "widget.loginview",
requires: ['Ext.form.FieldSet', 'Ext.form.Password', 'Ext.Label'],
config: {
    title: 'Login',
    scrollable: false,
    items: [
        {
            xtype: "toolbar",
            docked: "top",
            title: "Login",
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: "button",
                    ui: "back",
                    text: "Home",
                    itemId: "backButton",
                    width: 120,
                    height: 25
                },
                { xtype: "spacer" },
                {
                    xtype: "button",
                    ui: "action",
                    text: "Sign Up",
                    itemId: "signupButton",
                    width: 120,
                    height: 25
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            xtype: 'label',
            html: 'Login failed. Please enter the correct credentials.',
            itemId: 'signInFailedLabel',
            hidden: true,
            hideAnimation: 'fadeOut',
            showAnimation: 'fadeIn',
            style: 'color:#990000;margin:5px 0px;'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'fieldset',
            title: 'Login',
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    store: "Login",
                    placeHolder: 'Username',
                    itemId: 'userNameTextField',
                    name: 'userNameTextField',
                    required: true,
                    itemTpl: "{username}"
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'passwordfield',
                    store: "Login",
                    placeHolder: 'Password',
                    itemId: 'passwordTextField',
                    name: 'passwordTextField',
                    required: true,
                    itemTpl: "{password}"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            xtype: "toolbar",
            docked: "bottom",
            layout: {
                pack: 'center'
            },
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    itemId: 'loginButton',
                    ui: 'action',
                    text: 'Log In',
                    width: 120,
                    height: 25
                }
            ]
        }
     ],
    listeners: [{
        delegate: '#loginButton',
        event: 'tap',
        fn: 'onLogInButtonTap'
    },
    {
        delegate: "#backButton",
        event: "tap",
        fn: "onBackButtonTap"
    },
    {
        delegate: "#signupButton",
        event: "tap",
        fn: "onSignUpButtonTap"
    }]
},
onLogInButtonTap: function () {
    console.log("goLogCommand");
    this.fireEvent("goLogCommand", this);
},
onSignUpButtonTap: function () {
    console.log("signUpCommand");
    this.fireEvent("signUpCommand", this);
},
onBackButtonTap: function () {
    console.log("backToHomeCommand");
    this.fireEvent("backToHomeCommand", this);
}});
```

Register.js

```
Ext.define('RealApp.view.Register', {
extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
alias: "widget.registerview",
requires: ['Ext.form.FieldSet', 'Ext.form.Password', 'Ext.Label', 'Ext.util.DelayedTask'],
config: {
    title: 'Register',
    scrollable: false,
    items: [
        {
            xtype: "toolbar",
            docked: "top",
            title: "Register",
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: "button",
                    ui: "back",
                    text: "Back",
                    itemId: "backButton",
                    width: 120,
                    height: 25
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            xtype: 'fieldset',
            title: 'Register',
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    label: 'Username',
                    store: "login",
                    itemId: 'userNameTextField',
                    name: 'userNameTextField',
                    required: true,
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'passwordfield',
                    label: 'Password',
                    store: "login",
                    itemId: 'passwordTextField',
                    name: 'passwordTextField',
                    required: true,
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            xtype: "toolbar",
            docked: "bottom",
            layout: {
                pack: 'center'
            },
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: "button",
                    ui: "action",
                    text: "Register",
                    itemId: "registerButton",
                    width: 120,
                    height: 25
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    listeners: [{
        delegate: '#registerButton',
        event: 'tap',
        fn: 'onRegisterButtonTap'
    },
    {
        delegate: "#backButton",
        event: "tap",
        fn: "onBackButtonTap"
    }]
},
onRegisterButtonTap: function () {
    console.log("registerCommand");
    this.fireEvent("registerCommand", this);
},
onBackButtonTap: function () {
    console.log("backCommand");
    this.fireEvent("backCommand", this);
}});
```

Comment: Usually we don't save password because of security risk.. what exactly you tying to do with username and password ?

Comment: To login the apps.So, what is the another way and the best way would you choose for login?

Comment: you have post username and password to the server ?

Comment: I think so. But I really don't have any idea how it'll be working. First,I've try using Store(mvc method) but it's not working. Which database I should use to keep the user data?

Comment: database in sencha touch ?

Comment: Yes. Why? Is there any problem Mr.Viswa.

Comment: you can use localStorage or sql(websql)

Comment: Thanks for your info Mr.Viswa. Now on I'm try working with Mr.Barrett example using localStorage.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this little demo I created for you, it stores a username and password in local storage. Maybe this will help.

http://www.senchafiddle.com/#TRFry

Comment: Thank you Mr.Barrett. But according to your example,how the controller could works?

Comment: And Mr.Barrett, I'm using MVC method,so can you teach me how to create Store and Model also the Controller.

Comment: Take a look at these MVC tutorials provided by sencha, http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/video/mvc-part-1 and http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/video/mvc-part-2

Comment: anyways, can u teach me how to verify and validate the user input such as username and password.